# Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker arrow icon not showing on Safari and showing blue squares on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Datetime picker is working fine but the arrow to navigate through time and day are not showing properly.

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQEXg.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXOzN.png)

I've tried to set back the default option in Javascript using the following code :

```
 icons: {
        time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
        date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
        up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
        down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
        previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
        next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
        today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot',
        clear: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
        close: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
    }
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Be sure that all css and font were loaded properly.

Comment: No error in console. Icons come from bootstrap and are imported with the following link : <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Bootstrap V4, Glyphicons have been been removed. I fixed the missing arrow by using Fontawesome. Add these to the icons option.

```
    $('.dateP').datetimepicker(
    {

        icons: 
        {
            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        },
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',

        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'right',
            vertical: 'auto'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there's no glyphicon in your boostrap or something wrong with it so that nothing happend, first workaround is: implement  [fontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) then set:

```
$('.yourSelector').datetimepicker({         
     fontAwesome:'font-awesome'     
});
```

second workaround:
open boostrap-datetimepicker.js then replace

```
 headTemplateV3:   '<thead>' +
                      '<tr>' +
                      '<th class="prev"><i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i> </th>' +
                      '<th colspan="5" class="switch"></th>' +
                      '<th class="next"><i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i> </th>' +
                      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>',
```

width

```
headTemplateV3:   '<thead>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<th class="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"/></th>'+
                        '<th colspan="5" class="switch"></th>'+
                        '<th class="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"/></th>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</thead>',
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.dateP').datetimepicker(
    {

        icons: 
        {
            up: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            down: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        }
  });
```

In this way you can use your custom icons as glyphicons have been deprecated!