# Bootstrap 4 DateTimePicker not working. Icons not showing

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm on Rails 5.2.0. I'm implementing bootstrap datetimepicker with below code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' data-target-input='nearest'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" name="params['start_time']" />
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.20', '>= 2.20.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require popper
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap
//= require tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css";
```

I'm encoutering a problem where no icons are showing up on the page for the datetimepicker. [image]

Attached is the screenshot for reference. Can anyone please point out any fault here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't specify any icon class, if you see the html `i` tag has no font icon classes `<div class="input-group-text"><i class=""></i></div>`. If you are using font-awesome then place `<i class="fa fa-calendar">` to show calendar icon.

Comment: @ShivajiVarma My bad. I have edited my question. Adding an icon class doesn't work. Forgot to add that in the question

Comment: where is font awesome css?

Comment: please include font-awesome css on the page. https://fontawesome.com/icons
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @RaviMariya Thanks. Was missing the font-awesome css.

Comment: I found this answer and it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/49939325/1348129

Answer (score 3):

You must to include Font-Awesome CSS then include that in your HTML head tag:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

***Last version (6beta2):***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: Weird enough, including font-awesome@6.0.0-alpha did not match the required icons (fa-clock), so I assume font-awesome@4.7.0 is required unless the default icons are overwritten as show in the other answer by *David Vo*

Comment: The problem could be due to the integrity check (SRI). In addition to the referral link you will need to calculate the SRI again. This tool will do for you: https://www.srihash.org/

Answer (score 3):

I have updated the default setting of icons prop of DateTimePicker by below code, then it is working fine for me

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults, {
                icons: {
                    time: 'far fa-clock',
                    date: 'far fa-calendar',
                    up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
                    down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
                    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
                    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
                    today: 'fas fa-calendar-check',
                    clear: 'far fa-trash-alt',
                    close: 'far fa-times-circle'
                }
            });
```

Comment: Not having the font-awesome@4.7.0 dependency would explain the missing icons, you can override the icons as shown above, or [from the documentation](https://tempusdominus.github.io/core/Options/#icons)